How can I view the most recently created repositories by a GitHub user or organization?
I am looking at a GitHub user or organization, e.g. https://github.com/orgs/adobe-research/ How can I view the most recently created repositories?
I don't see any ~"sort by creation date" option:

Did I miss something? Are the most recently created repositories listed somewhere else?

Your best option might be to sort the repositories by "last pushed, descending order". Theoretically, newer repositories will have fewer interactions (pushes, forks, stars, updates, etc.).
